# Metapost won't compile from the command line

Tags: metapost

I just downloaded MiKTeX and started to learn Metapost. I created the text file `example.mp` and went to `cmd` with command "mpost example" and it says:

> "I can't open file 'example' "

I know that it installed correctly since it also says "This is MetaPost, version 1.803 [and so on, and so on...]", and the path is correct.

Comment: Try `mpost example.mp`, perhaps?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107489/17423

Comment: tried, wont work either.

Comment: And in `cmd` did you went to the correct folder? If you type `dir` and hit enter, can you see `example.mp`? Did you check the extension of `example.mp` (perhaps your editor added .txt)?

Comment: (To validate Ulrike's guess, Notepad will add `.txt` as an extension unless you explicitly tell it not to do so.)

Comment: Yes it did! the file is example.mp.txt. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And in `cmd` did you went to the correct folder? If you type dir and hit enter, can you see `example.mp`? Did you check the extension of `example.mp` (perhaps your editor added the extension `.txt`)?